# How to create a static function create table php?

Tags: php, function

I created the static function create table and insert, but I do not know how to use them to different databases.
examples:

```
        static public function createTableA($TABLE,$DATA) 
        {       
            $conn=self::getConnectionA();           
            $SQL="CREATE TABLE {$TABLE}"; 
            $SQL.=" (";
            foreach($DATA as$key) 
            {
                $SQL.=$key.","; 
            }           
            $SQL=rtrim($SQL,","); 
            $SQL.= ") ";            
            $result=$conn->query($SQL); 
            if(!($result)) 
            {
                return false; 
            } 
            else 
            {
                return true; 
            }           
            mysqli_close($conn);            
        }
        static public function createTableB($TABLE,$DATA) 
        {       
            $conn=self::getConnectionB();           
            $SQL="CREATE TABLE {$TABLE}"; 
            $SQL.=" (";
            foreach($DATA as$key) 
            {
                $SQL.=$key.","; 
            }           
            $SQL=rtrim($SQL,","); 
            $SQL.= ") ";            
            $result=$conn->query($SQL); 
            if(!($result)) 
            {
                return false; 
            } 
            else 
            {
                return true; 
            }           
            mysqli_close($conn);            
        }
```

w in the above example I would like to create static function SQL which I could use in both databases `[$conn=self::getConnectionA(); and $conn=self::getConnectionB();]`
Maybe something like this???

```
        static public function createTable($TABLE,$DATA) 
        {           
            $SQL="CREATE TABLE {$TABLE}"; 
            $SQL.=" (";
            foreach($DATA as$key) 
            {
                $SQL.=$key.","; 
            }           
            $SQL=rtrim($SQL,","); 
            $SQL.= ") ";
            return $SQL;        
        }
        static public function createTableA($TABLE,$DATA) 
        {       
            $conn=self::getConnectionA();
            $sql=self::createTable($TABLE,$DATA);           
            $result=$conn->query($sql); 
            if(!($result)) 
            {
                return false; 
            } 
            else 
            {
                return true; 
            }           
            mysqli_close($conn);            
        }
        static public function createTableB($TABLE,$DATA) 
        {       
            $conn=self::getConnectionB();
            $sql=self::createTable($TABLE,$DATA);           
            $result=$conn->query($sql); 
            if(!($result)) 
            {
                return false; 
            } 
            else 
            {
                return true; 
            }           
            mysqli_close($conn);            
        }
```

I am asking for a constructive opinion on this topic and proposals for a better solution, just please, examples of the code in the answers ,thanks and best regards.

Comment: Why not make $CONNECTION another parameter like $TABLE and $DATA?

Comment: can you give an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something more like this.

I cleaned it up to be a little less verbose, let me know if it isn't clear. But the main thing is just to allow the connection choice to be a parameter like TABLE and DATA are, calling it with 'A' or 'B'.

```
static public function _createTable($TABLE,$DATA) 
{           
    $SQL="CREATE TABLE {$TABLE}"; 
    $SQL.=" (";
    foreach($DATA as$key) 
    {
        $SQL.=$key.","; 
    }           
    $SQL=rtrim($SQL,","); 
    $SQL.= ") "; 
    return $SQL; // edit, added this           
}
static public function createTable($CONN,$TABLE,$DATA) 
{       
    switch($CONN){
      case 'A':
        $conn = self::getConnectionA();
        break;
      case 'B':
        $conn = self::getConnectionB();
        break;
    }
    $sql=self::_createTable($TABLE,$DATA);           
    $result=$conn->query($sql);
    mysqli_close($conn); 
    return (bool) $result;           
}
```

Comment: I noticed one thing - you had your `mysqli_close` after your `return` - but you'll never reach it in that case. It should go before.

Comment: and you think it will work with it?? $tablaA=ManagerBD::createTableA($tableA,array(
       "id int AUTO_INCREMENT",
       "PRIMARY KEY (id)"));
       
       $tableB=ManagerBD::createTableB($tableB,array(
       "id int AUTO_INCREMENT",
       "PRIMARY KEY (id)"));

Comment: I mean, you have to adjust it to fit the new code. Something more like: `$tablaA = ManagerBD::createTable('A', $table, array( "id int AUTO_INCREMENT", "PRIMARY KEY (id)"));`

Comment: well you're going to have to give me a little more info than that.

Comment: I think there is some mistake here `$sql=self::_createTable($TABLE,$DATA);`

Comment: Did you see I added an underscore to the beginning? Or else they'd both named createTable? Probably it should be renamed something better like "prepareSql" or something.

Comment: I see it, but retun false

Comment: You should probably put something in there to catch and show any SQL errors.

Comment: like this `static public function getConnectionA() 
  {       
   require"db.php";
   $conn=$connection;      
   if(mysqli_connect_errno()) 
   {
    $conn_errno=mysqli_connect_errno();
    $conn_error=mysqli_connect_error();
    echo$conn_errno."<br />".$conn_error;
    return false;           
   } 
   else 
   {          
    return$conn;           
   }        
  }`

Comment: what about the `CREATE TABLE` syntax?

Comment: this is a problem with what I wrote earlier, where substitution is `$SQL="INSERT INTO {$TABLE}"; 
   $SQL.=" (";
   foreach($DATA as$key=>$val) 
   {
    $SQL.=$key.",";
   }   
   $SQL=rtrim($SQL,",");
   $SQL.=") ";
   $SQL.="VALUES";
   $SQL.=" (";   
   foreach($DATA as$val) 
   {
    $SQL.="".$val.",";
   }   
   $SQL=rtrim($SQL,','); 
   $SQL.= ")";
   $result=$conn->query($SQL);` for this `$sql=self::_createTable($TABLE,$DATA);` in `createTable` function everything works

Comment: I found , missing `return $SQL;`